# deployment of Flask application to OpenShift

Tags: python, deployment, flask, openshift

I would like to deploy my application which works fine on my local unix server to OpenShift cloud. I registered there and checkout git repository. But I don't know what to do now.
Application in this repository has following structure:

```
/libs
/app.py
/setup.py
/wsgi
   static/
   application
```

but I don't know where I should copy my project in which files should be modified. My project structure is following

```
/domain.wsgi
/domain/
  app.py
  infrastructure.py
  models/
  static/
  templates/
  views/
```

domain.wsgi

```
import sys, os

current_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.append(current_dir)
from domain.app import app as application
```

app.py

```
from infrastructure import app
import views.index
import views.login
import views.logout
import models.sa
```

infrastructure.py

```
from flask import Flask, g
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from models.sa import get_user_class, UserQuery
from models.database import db_session

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://.............'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

## Set SQL Alchemy to automatically tear down
@app.teardown_request
def shutdown_session(exception=None):
   db_session.remove()

# Instantiate authentication
User = get_user_class(db.Model)

# config
app.config.update(
   DEBUG = True,
   SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxx'
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You files go under wsgi folder; please see this tutorial on how to deploy flask applications to OpenShift: http://www.paasmag.com/2013/01/08/beginners-guide-to-writing-flask-apps-on-openshift/